# How to extend ArgumentCountError?

Tags: php, exception, codeception

I try to use my Exception in value-object

My test:

```
public function testCreateCompanyWithoutAddress() {
    $this->expectException(CompanyWithoutAddressException::class);
    CreateCompanyBuilder::instance()->withAddress(new Address())->build();
}
```

My `CompanyWithoutAddressException` class:

```
class CompanyWithoutAddressException extends ArgumentCountError {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Company must have an address');
    }
}
```

but when I run a test I get:

> Failed asserting that exception of type "ArgumentCountError" matches
>   expected exception ... and at least 4 expected" at... instead of
>   Company must have an address

How can I use my Exception class when I call Address constructor?

```
public function __construct(string $country, string $city, string $street, string $house, string $building = '0') {
    if (!$country && !$city && !$street && !$house && !$building) {
        throw new CompanyWithoutAddressException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your extended exception type will not magically be thrown instead of the default one. You'll have to throw the exception yourself if you want to use it.

Comment: Sorry. i added a code in my question

Comment: `ArgumentCountError` will be thrown before your constructor is even invoked, because it's built-in for any function that doesn't get a right amount of arguments. I guess you could give `$country`, `$city` and the others a default empty value, but not sure why you would do that really. Can you elaborate on the goal of that test?